# Passing zero arguments as params -- where the behaviour is defined?

Tags: c#, arguments, specifications, parameters

C# spec. allows you to call a function

```
void foo(params int[] x)
```

with zero parameters. However, I didn't find in C# Lang. Spec. a word on further behaviour -- will foo get empty array or null reference? I checked also MSDN -- nothing.

Where the behaviour is defined?

**NOTE**: I am not asking how VS behaves, I am asking about design of the language.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Section 7.4.1 of the C# Language Specification (ref: [C# 3.0 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx))

> In particular, note that an empty
>   array is created when there are zero
>   arguments given for the parameter
>   array.

It's the last line of the section

Comment: MS well hide this info, I checked the params section ;-) Thank you very much.

Comment: One workaround for this issue: Create a overloaded version of constructor/method with zero arguments.  Ex: `void foo()` and `void foo(params int[] x)`

Comment: Thanks. Here is a new link that will point to what Anthoney is referring to.

[Argument lists -> run time evaluation of argument lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists)

Answer (score 14):

> 17.5.1.4 Parameter arrays
>
> A parameter array permits arguments to
>   be specified in one of two ways in a
>   method invocation:
>   • The argument
>   given for a parameter array can be a
>   single expression of a type that is
>   implicitly convertible (§13.1) to the
>   parameter array type. In this case,
>   the parameter array acts precisely
>   like a value parameter.
>  •
>   Alternatively, the invocation can
>   specify zero or more arguments for the
>   parameter array, where each argument
>   is an expression of a type that is
>   implicitly convertible (§13.1) to the
>   element type of the parameter array.
>   In this case, the invocation creates
>   an instance of the parameter array
>   type with a length corresponding to
>   the number of arguments, initializes
>   the elements of the array instance
>   with the given argument values, and
>   uses the newly created array instance
>   as the actual argument.

In the same section an example is given:

```
using System;
class Test
{
    static void F(params int[] args) {
        Console.Write("Array contains {0} elements:", args.Length);
        foreach (int i in args)
            Console.Write(" {0}", i);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Main() {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
        F(arr);
        F(10, 20, 30, 40);
        F();
    }
}
```

produces the output

```
Array contains 3 elements: 1 2 3 Array
contains 4 elements: 10 20 30 40 Array
contains 0 elements:
```

This example illustrates the expected behavior: empty array

Answer (score 0):

For the callee it is equal to `void foo(int[] x)` and passing `n` parameters will give you an array with `n` elements. So zero parameters will be translated into an int[0].